# How can I create this kinda of URL /{storeId}/employee with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm using *Laravel 6.x* to create a simple store management dashboard, and this is how I think it should work:

1. The owner login in our system
2. Select one store of a list that he owns
3. Now he would be redirect to a dashboard to that specific store
   I was thinking in do something like this: *http://127.0.0.1:8000/{storeId}/home* and with the **storeId** the dashboard could show every information related to it, I know how to do it in a totally improper way, something like:

```php
Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ], function(){
        Route::resource('/stores', 'StoreController');
        Route::resource('/{storeId}/warehouse', 'WarehouseController');
        Route::resource('/{storeId}/employees', 'EmployeesController');
    }
);
```

I kinda don't wan't to repeat the `/{storeId}` in every route, exist something to avoid it?
I thought to use the [Sub-domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing), but I think it doesn't fit in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-groups)

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{storeId}'], function () {
    Route::resource('/warehouse', 'WarehouseController');
    Route::resource('/employees', 'EmployeesController');
})
```

You can also go though [Get Dynamic Route Group Prefix Parameter](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-dynamic-route-group-prefix-parameter) example.